# Is there a way to make an insertion for a tree with the method insert only having value

Tags: java

Is it possible to make an insert methode like void insert(int value) for binary search tree usually you would have to have something like insert(Node node, int key).I would like to fill a tree with for example an integer array while still keeping the low insert run-time of ordinary insert method for a tree O(logn)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an insert method that creates the `Node` in the method. So instead of passing in the `Node`, you would do something like:

```
public void insert(int info) {
    Node temp = new Node(info);
    //insert like normal with temp
}
```

If you already have an `insert` method that accepts info and a `Node`, then this is even easier:

```
public void insert(int info) {
    Node temp = new Node(info);
    insert(temp, info);
}
```

And then when you want to insert from your `Array` you can simply do:

```
for(int num : arr) {
    insert(num);
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention that the method has to be void

Comment: @IVnoobSuck Updated